# How to find mp3 audio subsequence

Tags: audio, mp3

The problem: As the input there are two mp3 files.
First is a 24 hour mp3 record of today's radio broadcasting.
The second one is a one minute long record of the same radiostation, that was made during the day.
To be abstract the second file is a kind of "subsequence" of the first one.

Is there any way to automatically determine at which 'part' of the big file is located the little one?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is a duplicate. Have found that it was already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921381/finding-one-sound-file-inside-of-another